# Jarviswidget fullscreen not rendered properly with Highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts, widget

I use jarvis widget as a widget to render [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) inside the [jarvis-widget](http://data.edwardsaquifer.org/widgets.php) body.I use line chart to render matrix inside jarvis widget.charts are render properly inside jarvis widget out of the full screen mode.

This is a out of fullscreen mode
[image]

**Issue :**  When I click the fullscreen jarviswidget was resized properly but in that case, Highchart wasn't resized accordingly.

This is fullscreen mode. you can see chart was not resize accodingly
[image]

**More :**  But It works for [flot](http://data.edwardsaquifer.org/flot.php) charts. 
Hope a solution for that,Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that you can use chart.reflow() when you are resizing your window, it should help you with your problem: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.reflow

Comment: thanks it is works.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this problem by resizing chart inside onFullScreen call back function in jarviswidget

```
$('#widget-grid').jarvisWidgets({
        toggleClass: 'fa fa-minus | fa fa-plus',
        deleteClass: 'fa fa-times',
        editClass: 'fa fa-cog | fa fa-save',
        fullscreenClass: 'fa fa-expand | fa fa-compress',
        refreshButtonClass: 'fa fa-refresh',
        grid: 'article',
        onFullscreen: function () {
            $("#chartid").highcharts().reflow();
        }
    });
```